# How can I check if resume is supported when using python FTP library?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a script that uploads files to FTP servers in Python. I already hacked up a way to resume unfinished uploads, but now I'm wondering if it was possible to check if resume is supported without 'just trying it'?

Comment: When in doubt, RFC to the rescue https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt

Comment: Could you please break that a bit down for me? I'm not a native English speaker and that's very confusing.